Numbers in dashboard graph differ from numbers in report graph
And before you reply: did you turn on "Use chart settings from report"?
Yes, it is turned on. Also: the dashboard does not have a filter. When editing the graph widget in the dashboard, the preview is correct, it gives the correct numbers. But upon completion, or refresh, of the dashboard, all columns have lower numbers than what they should be.
It's a simple bar graph, grouping by date, nothing more, so no colouring. I am sysadmin, so I can see all data. The property of the dashboard is View Dashboard As me.
Report diagram:

Dashboard diagram:

I have highlighted one day. But note that the report graph has many data points over 6k, while the dashboard graph has none of those.
Update: the dashboard, of which the graph is a part, contains about 20 graphs. This particular graph seems to be the only one with a problem. As an experiment, I have created a new dashboard, containing only the report graph. And then there are no differences.
Apparently including the report graph in the other dashboard is causing some issues. But, as I stated before, the dashboard uses the report graph as-is and the dashboard does not have a filter.

The experiment, with a new dashboard containing only the relevant report graph, showed that it should be possible to use the report graph without problems in a dashboard.
I removed the report graph from the dashboard, added it anew, and voila, problem solved.
I guess somewhere some bits got mixed up.
